# Returns a null from html node

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am attempting to access the company name from this [page](http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE:CASC&fstype=ii).

Should return a node with innertext of "Cascade corporation" however I get null instead.

```
HtmlNode htest = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='appbar']/div/div[2]/div[1]/span");
```

what am I missing?

P.S. must work with Chrome

Comment: I can't find `Cascade corporation` anywhere on that page.

Comment: super sorry about that. just fixed it

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce your issue on my machine. I captured request & response data using Fiddler. I was surprised to notice that rendered html output from browser is different from my code.

From Fiddler the difference I noticed is the user agent value.

```
string url = "http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:TXN&fstype=ii";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"; // latest firefox 
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='appbar']/div/div[2]/div[1]/span")
//var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='appbar-snippet-primary']/span")
```

When I comment user agent line I am able to reproduce your issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes I get the correct result from your code. however it is a must that I get it to work with Chrome. any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "however it is a must that I get it to work with Chrome". I think Chrome is not required for this task as this is C# code and I believe you are writing code to scrape this site isnt? May be I'm wrong at understanding you?

Comment: I am writing it as part of a gift for someone who uses Chrome exclusively

Comment: John, I have no idea how it can be done in Chrome. I don't want to waste your time here. I don't do Chrome programming at all.

Answer (score 0):

on the page you  are linking to there's no element with the id `appbar` there's only a div with a class called `appbar-hide` and that's the only place appbar exist in the source.

When facing a problem like this try a step by step approach. First select the first node in your xpath Ie start with `HtmlNode htest = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='appbar']");` and it that returns null (which in will in this case) you've found where the error is. Then correct the error and either try the full xpath again if you feel confident that the rest is ok. If you then get an error again take it back to the second element Ie. `//*[@id='appbar']/div` and progress like this untill you get the element you want

Comment: There is a div with an id of appbar. It's in another div with an id of fjfe-click-wrapper.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko not on my machine

Comment: which browser. Are you checking in developer tools or the source code?

Comment: Tested in IE, Chrome and Firefox and the element is there.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko In chrome and tested in source as well as dev tools. Though the latter won't mater much since the difference would be due to JavaScript which is likely not executed before using HTmlAgilityPack

Comment: Why the dw? The answer both highlights a potential problem (it would seem the source is inconsistent based on Ash seeing something different than what I see) and it also helps OP solve similar problems in the future