# Force HtmlAgilityPack to use chrome

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

How can I force HtmlAgilityPack to use Chrome's interpretation of something in XPath?

for example these two lines of code point to the exact same thing on the web page, however the xpath is completely different.

for Chrome:

```
/html/body[@class=' hasGoogleVoiceExt']/div[@class='fjfe-bodywrapper']/div[@id='fjfe-real-body']/div[@id='fjfe-click-wrapper']/div[@id='appbar']/div[@class='elastic']/div[@class='appbar-center']/div[@class='appbar-snippet-primary']/span
```

for FireFox:

```
//*[@id='appbar']/div/div[2]/div[1]/span
```

I would like to use Chrome however I receive null for both queries.

Comment: Why would you have to use different xpaths in Chrome than in Firefox (or the other way around). They should yield the same results right?

Comment: no they dont. I got the chrome one from here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl

Comment: and the Firefox code from a previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993199/returns-a-null-from-html-node/10994715#comment14374589_10994715

Comment: But why wouldn't each work on the other browser?

Comment: the firefox one works for chrome and firefox. dont know how to test the other way.

Answer (score 1):

The Html Agility Pack has no dependency on any browser whatsoever. It uses .NET XPATH implementation. You can't change this, unless you rewrite it completely.

The HTML you see in a browser can be very different from the HTML you download for an url, as the first one could have been modified by dynamic code (javascript, DHTML).

If you have an existing HTML or url, we could help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found using a copied XPATH from Chrome:
- I had to remove all of the tbody elements and double up forward slashes and then following code would return the proper element.

> doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(
>                           "//html//body//center//table[3]//tr//td//table//tr//td//table//tr//td//table[3]//tr[3]//td[3]//table//tr//td//table");